# problema para hacer scraping en r

Tags: rstudio

Cuando trato de hacer scraping en una web para extraer los precios de los productos   como resultado obtengo numeric(0). 
Este es mi código

```
preciov <- lapply(paste("https://www.disco.com.ar/Comprar/Home.aspx#_atCategory=false&_atGrilla=true&_id=243210",1:3),
        function(url){  
           url %>% read_html() %>% 
           html_nodes(".grilla-producto-precio") %>% 
           html_text() %>%
           gsub('[\r\n\t]', '', .)
})

precio = unlist(preciov)
precio = as.numeric(precio)
precio = na.omit(precio)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contenido se carga dinámicamente desde [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo,

```
library(httr)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)

headers = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
cookies = c('ASP.NET_SessionId' = 't0xi0ybm4hzc2y55myqdvf45')

data = '{IdMenu:"243210",textoBusqueda:"", producto:"", marca:"", pager:"", ordenamiento:0, precioDesde:"", precioHasta:""}'

r <- httr::POST(url = 'https://www.disco.com.ar/Comprar/HomeService.aspx/ObtenerArticulosPorDescripcionMarcaFamiliaLevex', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), httr::set_cookies(.cookies = cookies) ,body = data)
res <- content(r,as="text") %>% jsonlite::fromJSON(.)
d <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res$d)
print(d$ResultadosBusquedaLevex[c('DescripcionArticulo','Precio')])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando introduzco el código sale este Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.

Comment: cookies = c('ASP.NET_SessionId' = '1zlka555aodouvu0ud042zmy')

Comment: El error persiste

Comment: https://www.disco.com.ar/Comprar/Home.aspx#_atCategory=false&_atGrilla=true&_id=2432101  >>No se encontraron resultados.